# SPFx: sort pnp.sp.search how to make query search results by start and end date

Tags: search, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, react

I am making simple SPFx search for SharePoint folders and files. How can I make search query that search results between start and end dates using QueryTemplate or Refiners properties?

```
return new Promise<ISearchResult[]>((resolve, reject) => {
        pnp.sp.search({
            Querytext: query,
            RowLimit: 20,
            StartRow: 0,
            QueryTemlate:'search query there',
            Refiners: 'search query there',
            SelectProperties: ["Title", "Author", "Path", "FileType","RefinersTextListOWSTEXT"]
        })
            .then((results) => {
                results.PrimarySearchResults.forEach((result) => {
                    _results.push({
                        title: result.Title,
                        description: result.HitHighlightedSummary,
                        link: result.Path,
                        author: result.Author,
                        filetype: result.FileType,
                        path: result.OriginalPath

                    });
                });
            })
            .then(
                () => { resolve(_results); }
            )
            .catch(
                () => { reject(new Error("Error")); }
            );
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use query in `QueryTemplate` like:

```
QueryTemplate:"(LastModifiedTime>=2019-04-26 AND LastModifiedTime<=2022-11-03)"
```

Full code:

```
pnp.sp.search({
                Querytext: query,
                RowLimit: 20,
                StartRow: 0,
                QueryTemplate: "(LastModifiedTime >= " + stdate + " AND LastModifiedTime <= "+enddate+")",
                SelectProperties: ["Title", "Author", "Path", "FileType", "RefinersTextListOWSTEXT","ModifiedOWSDATE"]
            })

                .then((results) => {
                    results.PrimarySearchResults.forEach((result:any) => {
                        _results.push({
                            title: result.Title,
                            description: result.HitHighlightedSummary,
                            link: result.Path,
                            author: result.Author,
                            filetype: result.FileType,
                            path: result.OriginalPath,
                            culture: result.ModifiedOWSDATE
                        });
                    });
                })
                .then(
                    () => { resolve(_results); }
                )
                .catch(
                    () => { reject(new Error("Error")); }
                );
```